# how to change the size of a single character at the head of a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview where the HeaderText of one of the columns is define as:

```
dgvCompras.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Tipo  ▲";
```

What I want is that the triangle appears smaller.

Comment: Is it WinForms?

Comment: Y es, it is. I devlope in C# (Community 2015). This is a Desktop App. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ▲ (BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE [U+25B2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b2/index.htm)) use ▴ BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE [U+25B4](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b4/index.htm))

Comment: Thanks you. My problem was solved with dgvCompras.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Tipo  \u25B4";

Comment: Although it is more elegant with  dgvCompras.Columns[3].HeaderText = "F. Emisión   \u2B9D";

Comment: Sorry...   dgvCompras.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Tipo \u2B9D";

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest to choose a Font which contains the ▲ in smaller size. That would be the most easiest and efficient method.

Comment: How do I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Check this site for generating custom fonts.http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-your-own-fonts-symbols-characters-windows/

Comment: Thanks you. It's very interesting.